# GWT Stacklayout panel does not show the child widget except header

Tags: uibinder

I am using stacklayout panel for the first time.
I read the gwt docs and found that parent for this should be a type of Layout.

Below is my code for parent widget("EncounterViewImpl") which creates a TabLayout panel and my widget "StudyViewImpl" is on one of the tabs of this tablayout.

EncounterViewImpl.ui.xml(Parent)

```
  <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder
   xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
   xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
   xmlns:hpi="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.hpi"
   xmlns:history="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.history"
   xmlns:medication="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.medication"
   xmlns:physical="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.physical"
   xmlns:diagnosis="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.diagnosis"
   xmlns:wellness="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.wellness"
   xmlns:study="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.study"
  xmlns:dental="urn:import:com.zoomcare.emrgwt.client.ui.encounter.dental">
<g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit="PX" barHeight="30" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g:tab visible="false">
        <g:header>
            Dental
        </g:header>
        <g:ScrollPanel width="98%" height="100%">
            <dental:EncounterDentalViewImpl ui:field="encounterDentalView"/>
        </g:ScrollPanel>
    </g:tab>
    <g:tab visible="false">
        <g:header>
            Study
        </g:header>
        <g:ScrollPanel width="98%" height="100%">
            <study:StudyViewImpl ui:field="studyView"/>
        </g:ScrollPanel>
    </g:tab>
   </g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

StudyViewImpl.ui.xml(Child)

```
  <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
 <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
            <g:StackLayoutPanel height="100%" width="98%" ui:field="stackPanel" >

            </g:StackLayoutPanel>
```

I want to add the widgets to stackpanel dynamically by its corresponding Activity class .StudyActivity calls setStudies(List list) after getting service response

Below is the code ..
StudyViewImpl.java

```
public class StudyViewImpl extends Composite implements StudyView {

private static LocalUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LocalUiBinder.class);
interface LocalUiBinder extends UiBinder<StackLayoutPanel, StudyViewImpl> {
}

private StudyInfoActivityPiece presenter;

@UiField
StackLayoutPanel stackPanel ;


public StudyViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    //stackPanel.setWidth("800");
}

  public void setStudies(List<ScheduledStudyGWT> studies){
    for(ScheduledStudyGWT study : studies) {
        VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        vPanel.setWidth("100%");
        vPanel.setHeight("100%");
        StudyInfoWidget infoWidget =  new StudyInfoWidget();
        infoWidget.setWidth("100%");
        infoWidget.setHeight("100%");
        infoWidget.populate(study);
        infoWidget.setReadOnly(false);
        ExamNoteWidget examNoteWidget =  new ExamNoteWidget();
        examNoteWidget.setWidth("100%");
        examNoteWidget.setHeight("100%");
        examNoteWidget.setExamNote(study.getExamNote());
        examNoteWidget.setReadOnly(false);
        InstructionsWidget instructionsWidget =  new InstructionsWidget();
        instructionsWidget.setInstructions(study.getInstructions());
        instructionsWidget.setWidth("100%");
        instructionsWidget.setHeight("100%");
        instructionsWidget.setReadOnly(false);
        vPanel.setVisible(true);
        vPanel.add(infoWidget);
        vPanel.add(examNoteWidget);
        vPanel.add(instructionsWidget);
        stackPanel.add(vPanel,createHeaderWidget(study.getOrderedLab().getLab().getName()),30);
    }
}

private Widget createHeaderWidget(String text) {
    HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    hPanel.setHeight("100%");
    hPanel.setSpacing(0);
    hPanel.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    HTML headerText = new HTML(text);
    hPanel.add(headerText);
    return new SimplePanel(hPanel);
}
```

}

When I run the above code I see that setStudies method  is called by passing a proper list of objects but on the browser i see only headers.

Please help me figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue fixed using StackPanel.I am running in quirk mode so shifted to StackPanel instead of StackLayoutPanel which is supported only in standard mode.